# regex text parser

Tags: pandas

I have the dataframe like

```
ID  Series
1102    [('taxi instructions', 13, 30, 'NP'), ('consistent basis', 31, 47, 'NP'), ('the atc taxi clearance', 89, 111, 'NP')]
1500    [('forgot data pages info', 0, 22, 'NP')]
649 [('hud', 0, 3, 'NP'), ('correctly fotr approach', 12, 35, 'NP')]
```

I am trying to parse the text in column named `Series` to different columns named `Series1` `Series2` etc upto the highest number of texts parsed.

```
df_parsed = df['Series'].str[1:-1].str.split(', ', expand = True)
```

something like this:

```
ID  Series  Series1 Series2 Series3
1102    [('taxi instructions', 13, 30, 'NP'), ('consistent basis', 31, 47, 'NP'), ('the atc taxi clearance', 89, 111, 'NP')]    taxi instructions   consistent basis    the atc taxi clearance
1500    [('forgot data pages info', 0, 22, 'NP')]   forgot data pages info      
649 [('hud', 0, 3, 'NP'), ('correctly fotr approach', 12, 35, 'NP')]    hud correctly fotr approach
```

Comment: Only the text to be parsed, dont know why other info (the numeric ones and NP and all are also coming in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your final result is not easy to understand, but maybe you can follow the concept to create your new columns:

```
def process(ls):
    return ' '.join([x[0] for x in ls])

df['Series_new'] = df['Series'].apply(lambda x: process(x))
```

And if you want to create N new columns (`N = max_len(Series_list)`), I think you can calculate N first. Then, follow the concept above and fill in NaN properly to create N new columns.

Comment: yes yes the output dataframe is wrong from my side , it should ne something like this.ID Concept1 Concept2 Concept3
1102 taxi instructions consistent basis the atc taxi clearance
1500 forgot data pages info  
649 hud correctly fotr approach

Comment: I got this error:- TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable